# How to compare two BSON objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, equals, bson

How to compare two **BSON** objects in javascript?

I have two different(supposedly) BSON objects `a` and `b`. I need to compare them and check whether they are same

These bson objects have binary data in the following format

```
{
   "_data" : <BinData>
}
```

Will this work  `if(a == b){ yes_they_are_same! }`?

Would be great if there is a way to find out the difference

Comment: What do you mean by "BSON objects"? Do you want to compare two typed arrays?

Comment: How are you creating these "bson objects", where do they come from? What library are you using?

Comment: @Bergi BSON objects are created using binary data. I've edited my question

Comment: And what's `BinData`? Again, what library did create them?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resume-tokens

Comment: So it's actually a [`Binary` instance](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Binary.html)?